# What is the difference between high-Z (high impedance ) and open circuit?

Tags: power-electronics, impedance, electronic-load

I cannot understand exactly difference between them. I am not sure about this topic.

I think high-Z means "temporarily open circuit."

Can you explain the difference to me?

Comment: Hi-Z could mean permanently open circuit too. You "brought up" the subject. You need to "bring-up" a bit of context because, as it stands the question will likely be closed on the grounds of insufficient information.

Comment: An open circuit is high impedance. In which context are you asking?

Comment: To me it's semantics - open-circuit implies no connection / floating, whereas Hi-Z implies a circuit which has been deliberately put into a near-floating state. So I somewhat agree with your premise.

Comment: @AdamLawrence True 90% of the time I think. But if talking about a relay switching a motor I would say open-circuit instead of high impedance. And no one would ever call opamp inputs open circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between what we call an "open circuit", and what we call a "high-Z" or "high impedeance" circuit lies in our expectations.

A theoretically open circuit, or an ideal open circuit has "infinite" impedance, (infinite Z) and no current flowing through it. Of course there is no perfect insulator. There is alsways some finite, yet high, impedance in what we call an open circuit.

If we treat a real circuit as theoretically open, that means we are not interested in the small current that may actually flow through it. On the other hand, if we treat a circuit as high Z, that means that there are situations where we want to take into consideration the small current that may flow through it.

As an example, in the LED circuit below, we are not interested in the truly miniscule current that flows through the insulation of the switch when the switch is off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3grYT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, in next circuit, (which admittedly has few practical uses by itself besides illustrating a point) we *are* interested in the very small current that flows through the resistor, because it serves to "bleed" or discharge the capacitor when the capacitor is disconnected from a voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxqJTD.png)</sup>

So, the difference between "high-Z" and "open circuit" comes down to whether we deem it appropriate to ignore the very small currents (in some cases, nearly undetectable, but theoretically predicted currents) that flow through all physical circuits.

Answer (score 3):

High-Z usually means, that the resistance is sufficiently high to be treated as an open-circuit.

However, High-Z also implies, that there is a defined potential on the connection.
Open Circuit usually means just that: no connection and no defined potential.

Lots of inputs require that the input voltage is defined.  Leaving them unconnected might result in surprising behaviour due to EMC.

Answer (score 2):

If an impedance is referred to as 'high-Z', it usually means it's high enough to be approximated as an open circuit, in the context of other impedances in the system.

For instance, my 1 MΩ // 30 pF oscilloscope input is high-Z if I'm measuring audio in 600 Ω, but not if I'm measuring signals at the other end of a MΩ resistor, or trying to measure RF (the 30p pF is too low impedance at RF)

Answer (score 1):

Small signal : they are approximately the same (within the odd microamp). For accuracy you would have to look at leakage current specs for a High-Z input or output.

Large signal : once signals reach or exceed the supply rails, you can no longer assume "High-Z" signals are high impedance, because of (first) protection circuits like diodes to the supply rails starting to conduct, and (second) device failures if the protection ccts weren't adequate.

Answer (score 1):

Open circuit almost means infinite impedance and implies zero current flowing to the point of non-functioning.

High-Z means high, but not infinite impedance and implies very little current flowing. It is always used over open-circuit if there is enough current for a potential to form for the purposes of communicating a signal.

An opamp input is high impedance, not open circuit because a potential is definitely there even if the current is very low.

There is a gray area though. If you open a relay, that is open-circuit but if you turn off an open collector output so the transistor blocks current, that is high impedance. It is sort of convention to pair terms up that way, possibly because transistors have leakage even when blocking whereas relays do not.